# Why does sort in R return me a vector shorter than the input?

Tags: r

Why does sort in R return me a vector shorter than the input?

```
> length(x)
[1] 14434
> length(sort(x))
[1] 14416
```

My vector is too long to be posted here. But how is this even possible?

Comment: Because `sort` by default remove the `NA` you can check `length(na.omit(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is by default `sort` uses `na.last = NA` and it gets removed after the `sort`ing.  If we specify `na.last = TRUE`, it will return the full vector

```
sort(x, na.last = TRUE)
```

---

It can be checked in the `methods` for `sort` i.e. `sort.default` calls `sort.int` (based on the condition `if (is.object(x))` - returning FALSE`and within`sort.int`, it does remove the` NA`in`radix`

```
...

if (index.return && is.na(na.last)) {
        x <- x[!is.na(x)] # removes the NA
        na.last <- TRUE
    }
```

..

and in other places where it removes those NA

---

Reproducible example

```
v1 <- c(2, 3, NA, NA, 5)
sort(v1)
#[1] 2 3 5
sort(v1, na.last = TRUE)
#[1]  2  3  5 NA NA
```